# why i cannot search for my random generate value?

Tags: java

So far i can generate random 20 number that i want...but when i want to Search for my random 20 number ...it alwayS Show "the number you enter cannot found " why ???how do i Search the value from the number i generated ?  would be happy if Someone can teach me how to do .

```
package labtask.pkg5;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Labtask5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int search = 1;
        int[] array = new int[20];
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();         //generate random number
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
        }
        while (search != 0)              //Search for a number
        {
            System.out.println("Search a number");
            search = read.nextInt();
            if (SearchValue(search, array) == true) {
                System.out.println("The number you enter been found");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The number you enter did not found");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean SearchValue(int search, int[] array) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
            if (search == array[y]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should assign the generated number to aour array

Answer (score 3):

1 things:

you are printing 20 random numbers only, but not assigning it into the array:

```
for (int x = 0; x<20; x++){
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));    
}
```

do instead:

```
for (int x = 0;x<20;x++) {
    array[x] = r.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(array[x]);
}
```

on the other hand, the method:

```
 SearchValue(int search, int[] array)
```

is returning some boolean immediantly after checking the 1st element in the array, you need to BROWSE the whole array instead...

do instead something like:

```
public static boolean SearchValue(int search, int[] array) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        if (search == array[y]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is with this function:

```
public static boolean SearchValue(int search, int[] array) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        if (search == array[y]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You will **always** return either true or false on the first iteration of the loop and you will never get past `y = 0`.

Additionally, you do not need to hardcode the value 20. The array is aware of its own size.

I would expect this to look like:

```
public static boolean SearchValue(int search, int[] array) {
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        if (search == array[y]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And the array is still full of 0. Both answer are complementary ;)

Comment: thx micheal  ...very appreciate it ....can i know what my second problem ??